# Set gradient background in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I am trying to add gradient background only for a few pages,

***login.page.html***

```
<ion-header>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="bg-class">
   <p>lorem</p>
</ion-content>
```

**_login.page.css**

```
.bg-class{
    background-image: linear-gradient(197deg, rgba(100,100,100,1) 0%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 13.5%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 33.33%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important
}
```

This is not working, can i know where I am going wrong? Is there anything else i need to be doing to get this one to work.

Comment: Seems to work fine when I try it in a Stackblitz... https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tgvqfw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.css

Comment: Do i need to do anything apart from just defining the CSS like importing and declaring?

Comment: You need to make sure your component has the `stylesUrls` set if you've not done that

Comment: styleUrls is present, but still it isnt working for me.

Comment: With the information you've given, I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Can you create a StackBlitz that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ionic 4, you need to use CSS variables to theme the `ion-content`.

Simply change your CSS rule as follows:

```
.bg-class{
  --background: linear-gradient(197deg, rgba(100,100,100,1) 0%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 13.5%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 33.33%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
}
```

Here is the [theming guide](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/basics/)

Comment: Thank you It worked. Is there link where the list of all the variables are available ?

Comment: Any Idea on how we can change the color ion-text border ?

Comment: @akshayramesh Unfortunately, [the page on their docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/api) doesn't seem to work, however if you inspect the page in your browser you may be able to find it in the developer tools. CSS variables all start with `--`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

***login.page.html***

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="bg-class">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**_login.page.css**

```
.bg-class{
           background-image: linear-gradient(197deg, rgba(100,100,100,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 13.5%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 33.33%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
 }
```

Comment: This is not adding the gradient to the entire screen.